# Implementing two pointer technique in sets in C++

Tags: c++, set

I am trying to implement two pointer technique in sets in C++.
I want to check if the difference of two elements of a set equals to a constant 'k'.

```
void solve(int n,int k,set<int> s){
    auto it_1 = s.begin();
    auto it_2 = s.end();
    while(it_1 < it_2){ 
        if(*it_2 - *it_1 == k){
            cout << "YES" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if(*it_2 - *it_1 > k){
            it_1++;
        }
        else{
            it_2--;
        }
    }
    cout << "NO" << endl;
    return;
}
```

I get the following error:-

> error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator' and 'std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator')
> while(it_1 < it_2)

I do know that the error is because I am comparing two pointers. How can I check whether the **it_1** is behind **it_2** ?

Comment: That isn't the only problem. `if(*it_2...` will dereference the end iterator of the sequence on first inception, which invokes *undefined behavior*. Also, I don't see what `n` has to do with any of this, so it isn't clear why it is even provided as a parameter to `solve`. it is never used in the function.

Comment: *...I am comparing two pointers...*  Incorrect, you are comparing two **iterators**.  And those iterators support `==` and `!=`, but do not support `<`.

Comment: `void solve(int n,int k,set<int> s)` -- This suspiciously looks like one of those questions from those "online competition coding" websites.  If this is where you got this question from, you won't learn C++ going to those sites.

Comment: "How can I check whether the it_1 is behind it_2" - you're collapsing from left and right with one move of one iterator (1 or 2) per iteration. So, just using `while (it_1 != it_2)` should work. Caveat: that won't solve the dereference of the end-iterator I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wrote the code in ```solve()``` for better understanding of the problem. This is not a problem from any of the coding competitions. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @WhozCraig I was earlier using arrays, hence you see ```n``` in the code. Thank you for your comment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems with the iterators can be solved quickly.

- Simply use the `!=` operator instead of `<`
- Do not start from the `end`-iterator, but one element before. Because the `end`-iterator points at past the last valid element.

But, unfortunately the 2 pointer approach will not work, if you want to find a pair with a given delta. The reason for that is that you would increment one pointer too much, and the delta can never be reached. With summing up the values, it would work.

Let us take your initial approach as an example fix the minor bugs and look at the output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void solve(int k, std::set<int>& s) {
    auto it_1 = s.begin();
    auto it_2 = std::prev(s.end());
    while (it_1 != it_2) {
        std::cout << *it_1 << ' ' << *it_2 << '\n';
        if (*it_2 - *it_1 == k) {
            std::cout << "YES\n";
            return;
        }
        else if (*it_2 - *it_1 > k) {
            it_1++;
        }
        else {
            it_2--;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "NO\n";
    return;
}
int main() {
    std::set test{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 };
    solve(8, test);
}
```

This will result in:

```
1 89
2 89
3 89
5 89
8 89
13 89
21 89
34 89
55 89
NO
```

You see the problem.

By the way, finding the sum is a typical use case for the 2 pointer approach. Then it will always work. The set is sorted. And we start with the min value at the beginning and the max value at the end. So building the first sum will give us the maximum possible sum. Then we move first the pointer with the small numbers, or depending of the sum, decrement the upper pointer.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void solve(int k, std::set<int>& s) {
    auto it_1 = s.begin();
    auto it_2 = std::prev(s.end());
    while (it_1 != it_2) {
        std::cout << *it_1 << ' ' << *it_2 << '\n';
        if (*it_2 + *it_1 == k) {
            std::cout << "YES\n";
            return;
        }
        else if (*it_2 + *it_1 < k) {
            it_1++;
        }
        else {
            it_2--;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "NO\n";
    return;
}
int main() {
    std::set test{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 };
    solve(8, test);
}
```

Output:

```
1 89
1 55
1 34
1 21
1 13
1 8
1 5
2 5
3 5
YES
```

---

---

But how to solve the delta problem?

What will always work is brute forcing. This will lokk like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

void solve(int k, std::set<int>& s) {
    auto it_1 = s.begin();
    auto it_2 = std::next(s.begin());

    while ((it_1 != s.end()) and (it_2 != s.end())) {
        std::cout << *it_1 << ' ' << *it_2 << '\n';
        if ((it_1 != it_2) and ((*it_2 - *it_1 == k) or (*it_1 - *it_2 == k))) {
            std::cout << "YES\n";
            return;
        }
        else if (*it_2 - *it_1 < k)
            ++it_2;
        else
            ++it_1;
    }
    std::cout << "NO\n";
    return;
}
int main() {
    std::set test{ 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 };
    solve(8, test);
}
```

With the following output:

```
1 2
1 3
1 5
1 8
1 13
2 13
3 13
5 13
YES
```

A little bit optimized opproach would use a `std::unordered_map`. But maybe this is too much for here.